# node.js - simple hello world app don't work

Tags: node.js

I'm trying hard to learn Node.js, but because the lacks of tutorials I having hard time learning it.

So I have the following code -

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();

http.request(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200);

    res.write("Hello World");

    res.end();
});

server.listen(5000);
```

So after I compile it, I type in chrome `localhost:5000` and crap it does not work.. 
What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you start the app via `node [appname]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [nodejs site](http://nodejs.org/)

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200);

    res.write("Hello World");

    res.end();
});

server.listen(5000);
```

Comment: ohh I see thanks, but I'm trying to do this http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: I think request actually makes an http request, which is not what you want

Comment: @IsraelG. That is for acting as an http client.  If that's really what you want, then you shouldn't expect to be able to access it as if its a server.